# Почему некорректно работает Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

На сайте перестал корректно работать плагин Contact Form 7. Заявки на почту приходят, но при отправке заявки с любой формы появляется анимация лоадера и не исчезает, как и не появляется сообщение об отправке.

Comment: Какая версия Contact Form 7? Начиная с 4.8, были такие проблемы со скриптами.

Comment: Версия 5.1.1, а что можно сделать? Как я понял не работает ajax. jquery

Comment: Поставьте версию 4.7. Это последняя известная мне версия, где не было конфликта скриптов.

Comment: Откат тоже не помог

Comment: Не знаю тогда. Это конфликт скриптов, но я с ним не разбирался.

Comment: Откат помог все таки , кэш удалил. Спс